# Odoo 15 website_sale - search for custom attribute

Tags: odoo, odoo-15

I need to search for a custom attribute (text - i created a controller in my custom module and added this code:

```
from odoo.addons.website_sale.controllers.main import WebsiteSale
from odoo.osv.expression import OR

class WebsiteSaleInherit(WebsiteSale):
    def _get_search_domain(self, search, category, attrib_values, search_in_description=False):
        print("in custom controller")
        # Call the super method to get the initial domain
        domain = super()._get_search_domain(
            search, category, attrib_values,
            search_in_description=search_in_description
        )

        if search:
            domain = OR([domain, [('wine_award', 'ilike', search)]])
            print(domain)
        return domain
```

The code get's called, but the filter doesn't have any effect (doesn't work)

The attribute is defined like this:

class Wine(models.Model):
`_inherit = 'product.template' wine_award = fields.Text(string="Wine award")`

I've implemented the code and when i print from the code i can see, that the controller is called and the domain gets changed:

print(domain) in the controller gives:

`['|', '&', '&', ('sale_ok', '=', True), ('website_id', 'in', (False, 4)), '|', '|', ('name', 'ilike', 'Yves'), ('wine_award', 'ilike', 'Yves'), ('product_variant_ids.default_code', 'ilike', 'Yves'), ('wine_award', 'ilike', 'Yves')]`

Comment: As far as i can see, that domain is only used for min and max price values. Whereas the real search is made on the `website.searchable.mixin` class.

Comment: I took the idea for this code from this sources: https://www.odoo.com/de_DE/forum/hilfe-1/odoo-14-ecommerce-website-search-by-product-s-custom-field-186592 and https://www.odoo.com/de_DE/forum/hilfe-1/odoo13-search-include-barcode-from-ecommerce-shop-191128 - So where do you have sources or examples?

Comment: I just looked up the code of module `website_sale` (E-Commerce). That [part](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/3add6b77a79300c5b08caa81fc95486d11cc5969/addons/website_sale/controllers/main.py#L316-L343)